# VBA - Reading PDF as String - Cannot sometimes but can other times - 'Run time error 62'

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

You can open PDFs in text editors to see the structure of how the PDF is written.

Using VBA I have opened a PDF as a text file and go to extract the text and save it as a string variable in VBA. I want to look through this text to find a specific element; a polyline (called sTreamTrain) and get the vertices of the polyline by using the InStr function.

When i add more vertices to the polyline I cannot seem to extract the text string of the pdf. I get the error 'Run time error 62' which I do not understand what it means or what about the PDF has changed to now have this error.

Attached (via the link) is a PDF that I can read (Document 15) and a PDF I cannot read (Document 16). I have checked in excel so see that the vertices are present in both files. Also there is a copy of my VBA script as a notepad document and also my excel file (but it is difficult to find in my excel file - the script is "Module 6" function called "CoordExtractor_TestBuild01()")

**Link:** 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zOhwnFWZZfy9bTAxKiQFSl7qiQLlYIJV

Code snippet of the text extraction process below to reproduce the problem (given an applicable pdf is used):

Sub CoordExtractor_TestBuild01()

'Opening the PDF and getting the coordinates

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String

'File Path of Text File
  FilePath = "C:\Users\KAllan\Documents\WorkingInformation\sTreamTrain\Document16 - Original.pdf"

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
  TextFile = FreeFile

'Open the text file in a Read State
  Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

'Store file content inside a variable
Dim Temp As Long
Temp = LOF(TextFile)

FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

'Clost Text File
  Close TextFile

End Sub

I would like someone to let me know what runtime error 62 is in this context and propose any workflows to get around it in future. Also, I would like to know whether there certain characters you cannot store as strings? - Perhaps these are included when I increase the number of vertices past a certain number.

Also I would prefer to keep the scrips quite simple and not use external libraries because I want to share the script when it is done so others can use it thus its simpler if it works without extra dependencies etc, however, any and all advice welcome since this is only the first half of this project.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"I cannot seem to extract the text string of the pdf"* - what exactly do you mean? Does your code find nothing or can it not properly process what it finds? Do you get some error? If yes, which one, on which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/858727/run-time-error-62-input-past-end-of-file-error-message-when-using-auto), this error is caused by the file containing

> ...blank spaces or extra returns at the end of the file or the syntax
>   is not correct.

Since your code works sometimes on documents with very similar names and content to documents where it doesn't work, we can rule out syntax errors in this case.

You can clean up the file contents before processing it any further by replacing the code at the top of your macro with the one below. With this I can read and extract information from your `Document16.pdf`:

```
Sub CoordExtractor_TestBuild01()


'Purpose to link together the extracting real PDF information and outputting the results onto a spreadsheet


'########################################################################################

'Opening the PDF and getting the coordinates
Dim n As Long
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String

'File Path of Text File
  FilePath = "C:\TEST\Document16.pdf" ' change path

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
  TextFile = FreeFile      

'Open the text file in a Read State
  Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

Dim strTextLine As String
Dim vItem As Variant

Line Input #1, strTextLine
vItem = Split(strTextLine, Chr(10))

' clean file of garbage information line by line
For n = LBound(vItem) To UBound(vItem)

    ' insert appropriate conditions here - in this case if the string "<<" is present
    If InStr(1, vItem(n), "<<") > 0 Then
        If FileContent = vbNullString Then
            FileContent = vItem(n)
        Else
            FileContent = FileContent & Chr(10) & vItem(n)
        End If
    End If
Next n

'Clost Text File
  Close TextFile


' insert the rest of the code here
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. As you said it works for what I need it for now which is fantastic! In future I want to make changes to the PDF so I would need to get the entire string so that I can manipulate it. Following on from your solution above I thought to replicate your Line Input approach but not filtering based on the character "<<". What I found was that I could not copy past the character at line 19 col 105 suggesting that the character at 106 is something I cannot input. Do you know if you can extend the characters available in VBA to be able to capture this?

Comment: The character at 106 is probably some invisible Ascii character. Try outputting it in the Immediate window with `Asc([string])`. If that's correct, you can simply add this line of code after `Line Input #1, strTextLine`: `Replace(strTextLine, Chr([Illegal Ascii Character code]), VbNullstring)`. If this works for you please consider accepting the answer. Thx.